# Opening and Closing Balance is wrt Debit and Credit amount

Tags: sql-server

I have this table structure and query written with the help of some guy here and it works perfect. I want to get the opening and closing balance between the dates. I have commented the date on which I want to get the date and if I run that date check the expected output I want is shown below.

Here is the structure and sample data:

```
DROP TABLE [TransactionMaster];
DROP TABLE [VoucherType];

CREATE TABLE [VoucherType](
    [VoucherTypeCode] [tinyint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (1, 'Cash Payment Voucher');
INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (2, 'Cash Receipt Voucher');
INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (3, 'Bank Payment Voucher');
INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (4, 'Bank Receipt Voucher');


CREATE TABLE [TransactionMaster](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [VoucherTypeCode] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [PayeeName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] datetime,
    [RefNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_TransactionMaster_tbl_VoucherType] FOREIGN KEY([VoucherTypeCode])
    REFERENCES [VoucherType] ([VoucherTypeCode])
)



INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (1, 2, 'Asim', '2018-03-21', 'CRV-0001-LHR');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (2, 4, 'Ali', '2018-03-21', 'BRV-2421-KHI');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (3, 1, 'Erick', '2018-03-23', 'CPV-5435-ISL');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (4, 3, 'Asim', '2018-03-24', 'BPV-2345-CAN');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (5, 2, 'Mehboob', '2018-03-25', 'CRV-2976-PSH');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (6, 1, 'Erick', '2018-03-25', 'CPV-2323-KOH');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (7, 1, 'Feroze', '2018-03-21', 'CRV-0531-SRG');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (8, 3, 'Ali', '2018-03-21', 'BRV-2001-RWP');



CREATE TABLE TransactionDetail
(
ID NUMERIC NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
TransactionCode bigint,
DrAmount NUMERIC,
CrAmount NUMERIC
);

INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (1, 1, '2500', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (2, 1, NULL, '1500');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (3, 1, NULL, '1000');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (4, 2, '1150', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (5, 2, NULL, '1150');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (6, 3, '600', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (7, 3, '400', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (8, 3, '200', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (9, 3, NULL, '1200');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (10, 4, '1000', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (11, 4, NULL, '1000');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (12, 5, '2400', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (13, 5, NULL, '1200');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (14, 5, NULL, '1000');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (15, 5, NULL, '200');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (16, 6, '2900', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (17, 6, NULL, '2900');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (18, 7, '700', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (19, 7, '300', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (20, 7, '2100', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (21, 7, NULL, '3100');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (22, 8, '500', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (23, 8, NULL, '500');
```

Here is the query

```
    with data1 as (
select a.id inid,a.VoucherTypeCode,PayeeName,MAX(c.DrAmount) InAmount,TransactionDate,RefNo,FullName from TransactionMaster a 
inner join  [VoucherType] b on a.VoucherTypeCode = b.VoucherTypeCode
inner join  TransactionDetail c on a.ID = c.TransactionCode
where a.VoucherTypeCode in (1,3)
GROUP BY a.id,a.VoucherTypeCode,PayeeName,TransactionDate,RefNo,FullName
),

data2 as (
select a.id outid,a.VoucherTypeCode,PayeeName,MAX(c.CrAmount) OutAmount,TransactionDate,RefNo,FullName from TransactionMaster a 
inner join  [VoucherType] b on a.VoucherTypeCode = b.VoucherTypeCode
inner join  TransactionDetail c on a.ID = c.TransactionCode
where a.VoucherTypeCode in (2,4)
GROUP BY a.id,a.VoucherTypeCode,PayeeName,TransactionDate,RefNo,FullName
)
select *,COALESCE(a.TransactionDate,b.TransactionDate) as FullDate from data1 a full join data2 b on inid = outid and a.TransactionDate = b.TransactionDate

--WHERE COALESCE(a.TransactionDate,b.TransactionDate) BETWEEN '2018-03-23 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-03-24 00:00:00.000'

order by FullDate
```

The expected output is provided below when you remove the commenting from the date check:

```
    inid                 VoucherTypeCode PayeeName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       InAmount                                TransactionDate         RefNo                                              FullName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        outid                VoucherTypeCode PayeeName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       OutAmount                               TransactionDate         RefNo                                              FullName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        FullDate                            Opening
-------------------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------
3                    1               Erick                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1200                                    2018-03-23 00:00:00.000 CPV-5435-ISL                                       Cash Payment Voucher                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                 NULL            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                    NULL                    NULL                                               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2018-03-23 00:00:00.000                 -50
4                    3               Asim                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1000                                    2018-03-24 00:00:00.000 BPV-2345-CAN                                       Bank Payment Voucher                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                 NULL            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                    NULL                    NULL                                               NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2018-03-24 00:00:00.000                 1150
```

The formula is that `(Opening+InAmount) - Out Amount` will be the `Closing Balance` and `Opening` will be previous rows `Closing Balance`.
So for first record opening will be 0 and closing will be 3100 and for second opening = 3100 and closing 3600 and so on.

If the VoucherType is 1 or 3 than I have to get the Credit Amount CrAmount and if the VoucherType is 2 or 4 then I need to get the Debit Amount DrAmount.

I've asked this question before and got the expected output as well but now the DB structure is changed a bit and I am unable to use that logic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the opening and closing balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205271/get-the-opening-and-closing-balance)

Comment: your sample data and the expected result matches ? Looks like the data in `TransactionDetail` contra itself. Total Dr = Cr

Comment: @Squirrel They should match, let me verify. And yes Total Dr = Cr for one Master record.

Comment: if it matches, then the Opening for all will be 0

Comment: @Squirrel Opening of the rows should be closing of previous row and closing of previous should be Receipt - Payment Amount and Receipt = Opening+Receipt Amount.

Answer (score 0):

basically it is the same as the previous query that i posted in your other thread.
Since the details in the other table TransactionDetail, you just need to INNER JOIN from the TransactionMaster to it and do the SUM(). I didn't verify the Dr - Cr or Cr - Dr logic. Please verify yourself.

```
SELECT  t.*, v.FullName, o.Opening
FROM    [TransactionMaster] t
        INNER JOIN [VoucherType] v  on  t.VoucherTypeCode   = v.VoucherTypeCode
        OUTER APPLY
        (   
        SELECT  Opening = sum(case when m.[VoucherTypeCode] in (1, 3) 
                                   then - ISNULL(d.CrAmount, 0)
                                   else + ISNULL(d.CrAmount, 0)
                                   end)
        FROM    [TransactionMaster] m
                INNER JOIN [TransactionDetail] d    ON  m.ID    = d.TransactionCode
        WHERE   m.TransactionDate < t.TransactionDate
        ) o
WHERE   t.TransactionDate   BETWEEN '2018-03-23' AND '2018-03-24'
order by t.TransactionDate
```

EDIT:
You don't need to use FULL JOIN to identify IN and OUT. Just use CASE statement as below

```
SELECT  inID     = case when t.VoucherTypeCode in (1,3) then t.ID end,
        inAmount = case when t.VoucherTypeCode in (1,3) then a.Amount end,
        outID    = case when t.VoucherTypeCode in (2,4) then t.ID end,
        outAmount = case when t.VoucherTypeCode in (2,4) then a.Amount end,
        t.PayeeName, t.TransactionDate, t.RefNo, 
        v.FullName, Opening = isnull(o.Opening, 0)
FROM    [TransactionMaster] t
        INNER JOIN [VoucherType] v  on  t.VoucherTypeCode   = v.VoucherTypeCode
        CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  Amount  = sum(case when m.[VoucherTypeCode] in (1, 3) 
                                           then -CrAmount
                                           else DrAmount
                                           end)
        FROM    [TransactionMaster] m
            INNER JOIN [TransactionDetail] d    ON  m.ID    = d.TransactionCode
        WHERE   m.ID    = t.ID
        ) a
        OUTER APPLY
        (   
        SELECT  Opening = sum(case when m.[VoucherTypeCode] in (1, 3) 
                                           then -CrAmount
                                           else DrAmount
                                           end)
        FROM    [TransactionMaster] m
            INNER JOIN [TransactionDetail] d    ON  m.ID    = d.TransactionCode
        WHERE   m.TransactionDate   < t.TransactionDate
        ) o
order by t.TransactionDate
```

Comment: But Opening should not be 0. Am I not providing correct data ?

Comment: Looking at your data, for each row in TransactionMater, the total Dr and Cr in TransactionDetail contra each other. So basically the Opening for each TransactionMaster will be 0

Comment: Maybe your data is not correct. Example, for `Asim`, the transaction is `Cash Receipt Voucher`. Why in `TransactionDetail`, you have  `Dr 2500`, `Cr 1500`, `Cr 1000` ?

Comment: That's the point. When the Voucher is `Receipt` it should get the `Debit Amount` i.e `Dr` which will always be one for one specific record and will always be equal to `Cr` Amounts `SUM`. Same is for `Payment Voucher` but in that case `Cr` will be only in one row and will always be equal to `Dr` Amounts `SUM`. For example for `Erick` where Master `ID` is `3`.

Comment: Sorry, rather lost here. Can you show how to get `-50` as opening for `Erick` ?

Comment: Yeah sure, give me a moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174636/discussion-between-doonie-darkoo-and-squirrel).

Comment: Seems we're headed in right direction but one thing. The opening in NULL until Erick's row and also the InAmount is going in negative although in the script there is no amount that is in negative.

Comment: use `ISNULL( o.opening , 0 )`. On the negative, I must have got the sign wrong. Change to `+CrAmount` and `+DrAmount` for the `CROSS APPLY ( ... ) a`